# Weird error when calling a web service from a Java SE client

Tags: java, web-services

I have a java SE client trying to talk to a J2EE web service.  We are using Axis 1.4, so when I try to make a call I get the error below:

```
'- Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.'

AxisFault

faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException  
faultSubcode:  
faultString: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.  
faultActor:  
faultNode:  
faultDetail:  
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.  
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the call:

```
        JRD_ServiceLocator jserv = new JRD_ServiceLocator();  
        Object arc[] = jserv.getserviceport( new URL("http://vpnl3-4102.fi.com:7110/jrds/services?WSDL")).getRefDataByQuery("MDS", "FX", "CCY", "CCY='A'");
```

Comment: The `Unable to find required classes` message is a warning only and unrelated to the AxisFault.  The server appears to be doing some DOM manipulation and has a bug.  Do you have an alternate way to verify that the service actually works?

Comment: there is a test wsdl client, will try hat.  but I don't even think the call is making it to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a PITA.  The web service itself was having problems.  I would have thought I would have got a different error, probably not forming the fault right on the server side.  Such is life when you are still using Weblogic 9.2.